# MonoTouch SupportedInterfaceOrientations not found

Tags: xamarin.ios, screen-rotation

In MonoTouch 6.0.10 with SDK 6.1 I have the following in a tabbarcontroller and navigationcontroller:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
{
    return true;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask SupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{
    var orientations = ParentViewController.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
    foreach ( var controller in ViewControllers )
        orientations = orientations & controller.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
    return orientations;
}
```

In AppDelegate I have:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations (UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
}
```

and in FinishedLaunching I have:

```
window.RootViewController = tabController;
```

In the tabbarcontroller and navigationcontroller this gets an error of the form 'HelloWorld.TabController.SupportedInterfaceOrientations() is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115).'

Any suggestion appreciated!

Bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewController` defines `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` which you can override in your `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` subclasses.

The C# compiler error message (and your code) shows that you're missing the `Get` prefix.

Comment: Thanks Poupou. You just beat me to it. We're a bit slow in the southern hemisphere.

Comment: Hi I am also having the same problem. Can you explain how did you solve yours.